# Is it possible to allow users to modify spinxbox value in Python tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm intending to create a sort of timer where the spinbox will be used to allow the user to adjust the timer settings. However, it would be quite annoying to keep having to click the arrow buttons to increment/decrement the values.

Here's the code that I'm currently working on.

```
from tkinter import *
import time


class mainmenu():
    def __init__(self, parent,NumDocks):
        self.Container = Frame(parent,width = 64,height = 20)
        self.Container.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.onMouseWheel)

        self.Title = Label(self.Container,text = "Kantai Manager",font = ("Arial", '20'))
        self.Title.pack()

        self.Docks = []
        self.DockTimeSelect = []
        for i in range(NumDocks):
            self.Docks.append(Frame(self.Container))
            self.Docks[i].pack()

            CurrentDock = Label(self.Docks[i],text = "Dock {}".format(i+1))
            CurrentDock.pack(side = 'left')

            CurrentDockTimer = Spinbox(self.Docks[i], from_=0,to=60,increment = 1)
            CurrentDockTimer.pack(side='left')

        self.Container.pack()

    def onMousewheel(self,event):
        pass

root = Tk()
root
mainmenu(root,2)
root.mainloop()
```

I'm not quite sure what to do for the onMousewheel function, and the command to bind the spinbox.

Comment: yes, it is possible. Show us a complete, working example that illustrates the problem you're having and perhaps we can help.

Comment: @BryanOakley I've updated the original post with my current code. Tbh I'm pretty lost as to how to go about writing the code for this. Still learning how to use tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to let the event invoke a button press. You can write your `onMouseWheel` function like:

```
def onMouseWheel(self, event):
    if event.delta > 0: # Check if the user scrolls up (positive) or down (negative)
        event.widget.invoke('buttonup')   # Invoke a press of the up button
    else:
        event.widget.invoke('buttondown') # Invoke a press of the down button
```